# WooCommerce REST API: Create order and generate payment links

Tags: vue.js, woocommerce, checkout

I'm wanting to replace the default WooCommerce checkout page with a VueJS application.

So far I've managed to:

1. use hooks to replace default checkout fields with vue app
2. gather customer information, cart, shipping & payment methods
3. create order using the [WooCommerce REST API](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/)

The REST API returns a payment_url upon success, however, this URL looks something like this

`HOST/checkout/order-pay/36/?pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order_AS4LMhlgr7fgi`

Ideally, I'd want this to be the payment gateway URL so that I can direct customers to finalize payment. I was hoping since I send the payment gateway with the order details that WooCommerce will process the order and if unpaid will return a payment gateway link.

Am I approaching this from the wrong angle? Is this doable or will I have to integrate each payment gateway and send requests/manage statuses via their API?

Answer (score 1):

So, I dug through WooCommerce to see how they do it and ended up using something similar. Hope it helps someone.

```
$order_id = $_REQUEST['order_id'];
$payment_method = $_REQUEST['payment_method'];

$available_gateways = WC()->payment_gateways->get_available_payment_gateways();
if ( ! isset( $available_gateways[ $payment_method ] ) ) {
    return;
}

// Store Order ID in session so it can be re-used after payment failure.
WC()->session->set( 'order_awaiting_payment', $order_id );

// Process Payment.
$result = $available_gateways[ $payment_method ]->process_payment( $order_id );

// Redirect to success/confirmation/payment page.
if ( isset( $result['result'] ) && 'success' === $result['result'] ) {
    $result['order_id'] = $order_id;

    $result = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_payment_successful_result', $result, $order_id );

    if ( ! wp_doing_ajax() ) {
        // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.SafeRedirect.wp_redirect_wp_redirect
        wp_redirect( $result['redirect'] );
        exit;
    }

    wp_send_json( $result );
}
```